# put a comma in the numbers just inside the string math

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a ٍstring of math numbers and I just want to put a comma in the numbers only for example:

```
String s="(1000+2000000-5000.8÷90000+√5×80000)";
```

I want to send it to a method to convert it to

```
String s="(1,000+2,000,000-5,000.8÷90,000+√5×80,000)";
```

i am using :

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.###");
String output = myFormatter.format(s);
System.out.println(output);
```

But get it error because there are operator '+-..'

Comment: You could use a regex to remove the operators and then feed it into your conversion.

Comment: java operator + - .. just work for type number ex : int, long, double

Comment: I need operator i cant remove it @bbnumber2

Comment: ok How java fix it like in my case @indralesmana

Comment: @mhd You could try splitting the string into an array of every element: `["1000", "+", "2000000", etc.]`, then use `DecimalFormat` on all of the numbers, and concat the strings back together again.

Comment: I suggest 3 step approach: split the string using operators as delimiters, format each element of the resulting array, use Arrays.toString() to get the output.

Comment: @bbnumber2 It doesn't have a fixed value, it's variable, simply this code for the calculator

Comment: @mhd That's fine. You would be using `String.split()` to define a new array which you would run your `DecimalFormat` on. My example array was just showing what I meant by elements.

Comment: @bbnumber2 You can give the code ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't a simple approach using `Matcher.appendReplacement` enough?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

....

static String formatMyString(String input){
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.*\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        String rep = myFormatter.format(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
        m.appendReplacement(sb,rep);            
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: get eror `incompatible types: StringBuilder cannot be converted to StringBuffer`

Comment: @mhd Then you are using Java 8 probably. Just change the StringBuilder to StringBuffer. I've updated my Answer.

Comment: ok worked but why take only three number after point like `0.53618` it take only `0.536` i wanr take all number after point

Comment: @mhd Because you use the format `###,###.###` which means 3 decimal places. If you want more just change your format to `###,###.#######` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

I'am using `str.toCharArray()`

```
public static String parseResult(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder currentDigits = new StringBuilder();

    for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            currentDigits.append(ch);
        } else {
            if (currentDigits.length() > 0) {
                String output = String.format(Locale.US,"%,d", Long.parseLong(currentDigits.toString()));
                result.append(output);
                currentDigits = new StringBuilder();
            }
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }

    if (currentDigits.length() > 0)
        result.append(currentDigits.toString());

    return result.toString();
}
```

and the call the function :

```
    String s="(1000+2000000-5000÷90000+√5×80000)";
    Log.e("s", s);
    String result = parseResult(s);
    Log.e("result", result);
```

the logcat :

```
E/s: (1000+2000000-5000÷90000+√5×80000)
E/result: (1,000+2,000,000-5,000÷90,000+√5×80,000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer only Please fix the error Decimal number to approve the answer `0.50008` i get `0.5,008`

Comment: @mhd what kind of results you want?

Comment: I want to work with decimal numbers too and he is putting a comma after a point as well .. I just want a point before